# How to escape "@" on REGEX mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this registry (my@mail.com) in tableMail.
If I use

```
    REGEXP '[[:<:]]my[[:>:]]'
```

my@mail.com is found.
If I use

```
    REGEXP '[[:<:]]my@[[:>:]]' or REGEXP '[[:<:]]my\@[[:>:]]'
```

my@mail.com is not found.

I think it is because "@" is a especial character. So how to escape it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "@" is not a special character in regular expression syntax. The match is failing because "m" is not a word boundary character, and you're forcing it to match word boundaries with `[[:>:]]`.

Demo:

```
mysql> select 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my[[:>:]]';
+-----------------------------------------+
| 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my[[:>:]]' |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       1 |
+-----------------------------------------+

mysql> select 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@[[:>:]]';
+------------------------------------------+
| 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@[[:>:]]' |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+

mysql> select 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@mail[[:>:]]';
+----------------------------------------------+
| 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@mail[[:>:]]' |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                            1 |
+----------------------------------------------+

mysql> select 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@mail.[[:>:]]';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 'my@mail.com' regexp '[[:<:]]my@mail.[[:>:]]' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

So take off the word boundary pattern if the next character in your string is not punctuation.

Comment: Hi Bill. It only find exactly pattern. That means your last expression only works if I use    '[[:<:]]my@mail.com[[:>:]]' not for    '[[:<:]]my@mail[[:>:]]'.

Comment: It is strange. If I copy your syntax it works. If I use your idea on my syntax. It not work.

Comment: This is what I have ig1@sd.com in table.

Comment: if I use SELECT USER_Pk FROM testdb.user where USER_MAIL REGEXP '[[:<:]]ig1@s[[:>:]]'; It will not find

Comment: if I use SELECT USER_Pk FROM testdb.user where USER_MAIL REGEXP '[[:<:]]ig1@sd[[:>:]]'; It will  find

Comment: if I use SELECT USER_Pk FROM testdb.user where USER_MAIL REGEXP '[[:<:]]ig1@sd.[[:>:]]'; It will not find

Comment: It has to do with the implementation of the word boundary pattern. Punctuation characters apparently do not match it.

Comment: Hi Bill, I found the solution. I was using with php. So I had to sacpe like this '[[:<:]]my@mail.\[[:>:]]'. Thanks